# Adding 30 days to DateTime with TimeZone is resulting to an error: "Call to a member function modify() on string"

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to add 30 days to the current day using the php modify() function and I also am putting timezone in the datetime here is my code:

```
$country_code = 'PH';
$timezone = \DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(\DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, $country_code);
$new_date = (new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone($timezone[0])))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$datetime = $new_date->modify('+30 days');  
$end_date = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I am getting the error:

> Call to a member function modify() on string

When I echo the $new_date it is  in proper MySQL datetime format 'Y-m-d H:i:s'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` as that creates `$new_date` as a string and not a DateTime Object that has a modify() method on it

```
$country_code = 'PH';
$timezone = \DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(\DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, $country_code);
$new_date = (new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone($timezone[0])));
$new_date->modify('+30 days');  
$end_date = $new_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Or you could do it all in one line

```
$new_date = (new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone($timezone[0])))->modify('+30 days')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly, I also realized the same thing, thanks for your comment tho

Answer (score 0):

ok this is crazy, I played with it and came up with a 1 liner solution..

```
$end_date = (new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone($timezone[0])))->modify('+30 days')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Apparently it should be formatted after being modified but in my earlier code it is being formatted first before modified then formatted once again.